# How can I exclude folders in All-in-One WP Migration?

Tags: wordpress, backup

I want to exclude the folder `/wp-content/uploads/download-manager-files` from backup because it contains files with several gigabytes of data.
For this I used the following hook in the `functions.php` of my theme:

```php
add_filter('ai1wm_exclude_content_from_export', function($exclude_filters) {

$exclude_filters[] = 'uploads/download-manager-files';

return $exclude_filters;
});
```

The backup runs successfully, but it includes the `/wp-content/uploads/download-manager-files` folder.

How do I apply the hook correctly to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The filter name has changed in the latest versions of the plugin, the new filter is `ai1wm_exclude_themes_from_export`

Full code to try:

```
// EXCLUDE NODE MODULES
add_filter( 'ai1wm_exclude_themes_from_export',
function ( $exclude_filters ) {
  $exclude_filters[] = 'theme-name/node_modules'; // insert your theme name
  return $exclude_filters;
} );
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/excluding-node_modules-via-filter-not-working-anymore/#post-14913666